# PRIORVALUE may not be used in this type of formula

Tags: formula

I try use this formula in SlaesForce, but I am getting this error " PRIORVALUE may not be used in this type of formula"

```
if(AND(
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"Closed"),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"Test"))), test=0
```

Comment: You can not use PRIORVALUE inside ISPICKVAL..you have to pass picklist field name to check with text.

Comment: this how the salesforce documentation says "ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE
(picklist_field), 
text_literal)"

Comment: check your evaluation criteria..it should be "created, and every time it’s edited" then it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating formula field this will wont give priorvalue for other fields..you can try to create workflow rule with criteria "created, and every time it’s edited", add a custom field on object and then update that field on the object.

Comment: Priorvalue function is only available with 
    Assignment rules,
    Validation rules,
    Field updates,
    Workflow rules if the evaluation criteria is set to Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and every time it’s edited.

check this link [Priorvalue function](http://na7.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_functions_i_z.htm#PRIORVALUE)